# Car not accelerating and over revving

Tags: ford, diesel, fiesta, rev-limiter

I have a Ford Fiesta 2010 Diesel 1.4. Recently the car has been struggle to accelerate when the gas pedal is being pressed. The engine still roars and the indicator will shoot up, but the car just over revs. If I press the gas pedal really gradually and slowly then it's fine, but the moment I put any normal amount of pressure it will over rev so I have to lift off and re apply pressure to the gas to drive properly. Couple things if it helps (1) Once i'm over 70 it doesn't happen much. I can put my foot down and the car will speed up as normal and (2) The car has not been serviced for just over a year. So yes I know I need to get this done asap, but not sure if this would be related? I do not know much about cars so don't want to go to any old mechanic and get conned so wanted to get a bit of an idea what it might be? Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the car have an automatic or manual transmission? How many miles on the Fiesta?

Comment: manual and about 57. i think the clutch was changed at 48

Comment: could it be the lack of service i.e. blocked air filter?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the clutch is slipping. In a manual transmission car, there is direct power going from the engine, through the transmission, to the drive wheels. There should be a linear curve between the engine and vehicle acceleration. There's only two places which might be in question here: the clutch and the tires. I really doubt you're burning rubber until you reach 70.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 whay not make this an answer?

Comment: @MadMarky - I was hesitant to put it as an answer because the user stated the clutch was changed only a few thousand miles ago. (Note: They do use "miles" in the UK, right? I mean, the M1 has a speed limit of 70mph, so would assume so?) I'd be surprised if a clutch would wear out so soon after installation, unless there was an issue with it in the first place (ie: wasn't actually done, but the OP was charged for it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and assuming you have a manual tranmission car, it looks like your clutch is worn out and slipping. Driving like this with an over-revving engine and a slipping clutch will only make things worse and more expensive to fix because other parts will now wear out and fail too. Get your clutch replaced ASAP.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Had it checked out. The injector seals were leaking/broken which was leaking causing the loss in power

Comment: I must say I was incorrect. While the leaking seals seem to fix the issue very temporarily, I did have to end up changing the clutch. You were correct! https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/57688/low-biting-point-after-clutch-change-ford-fiesta if you're interested